# What can a blocked user do on the site?

Tags: support, users

I came across a user account that appears to have been suspended for at least a few days, yet was "last seen" 6 hours ago. On other websites (outside the Stack Exchange network) being suspended can mean totally unable to log in and access the site. What does being blocked on SE do? Can the user log in and view the site, and is just unable to post (and anything that requires >1 reputation point)?

Comment: Since you don't need to be logged in at all (or even have an account) to read, it wouldn't seem to make sense to block suspended users from merely accessing the site.  At that point all we're doing is potentially denying an Enthusiast or Fanatic badge, and doing it for that reason feels a little petty to me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't think it's just petty, I think it may be harmful. If the purpose of suspension is to allow a user to reflect on unacceptable behavior, it might help to observe acceptable behavior during suspension, if the user intends to try using the site again in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suspension allows login and reading. It disallows posting, commenting, editing (including one's profile; h/t Monica Cellio), suggesting an edit, accepting an answer, voting (including voting to close/delete), flagging, reviewing, and offering/awarding a bounty. But the suspended user can reply to the site moderators (who message him when suspending; h/t DoubleAA) and can communicate with Stack Exchange employees via the contact link. [More details.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/161792)